# Local storage variables not showing in Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, microsoft-edge

I have a functioning react application that I've been running in Chrome and Edge (mainly). I store various information in local storage. The application is working as expected, but for some reason, I've lost the ability to view the local storage variables in Edge (developer tools). They are there, because the application is working fine; I just can't see them. In Chrome I can see them fine. They were visible in Edge until I started my latest sprint. I unwound all the changes, but they are still not showing. I've tried clearing all the browser data, rebooting, etc.

Has anyone else encountered such an issue? I am just looking for some ideas of how to investigate the issue, because my current enquiries have not been successful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "lost the ability to view" mean?  That the application local storage entry is completely missing or that it's there but has no domain entries or that your domain is missing or has no entries?  If there are domain entries, can you double click and manually add key-value pairs.  Does this problem affect all apps or only one app?  Also see: [Edge - View and edit local storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/storage/localstorage)

Comment: Thanks for responding. It means that the application local storage entry is there (when the application mounts, I can do, for example, `localStorage.getItem('rfrsh_dt')` and log the object to console), but the key itself ('rfrsh_dt) isn't listed under the domain entries (localhost in this case). In fact, there are no key/value pairs listed at all for this domain (despite having about a dozen other key/value pairs which can all be gotten and logged like 'rfrsh_dt'). The app itself is working fine, and in Chrome I can see all the variables listed ok.

Comment: This problem is apparently a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1408031&q=devtools%20local%20storage&can=2) in earlier versions of Chromium, on which Edge is based.  The bug status is "won't fix" because updating the browser has fixed the problem. Check your version and if it's 109 or older then this may apply to you.

Comment: Well done, you've got it. Interesting. I was assuming the issue had arisen because of a coding change I'd made, but then I recalled there was an update last week. I was on 109 (and everything was ok), but Edge was upgraded to 110 on the 9th Feb. It looks like this is what may have broken it. I downloaded the latest beta release and it is working again. So perhaps the official release will be ok from next month. Thanks for your help.